# How to write a OR query when number of parameters may change?

Tags: django, orm

I need to make a filter to show BookInstances with following conditions:

1. `BookInstance.public = True`
2. `BookInstance.owner != current logged in user`
3. `BookInstance.book.title.icontains('some text')`
4. `BookInstance.book.description.icontains('some text')`
5. `BookInstance.book.authors(id_in=some list of ids)`
6. `BookInstance.book.categories(id_in=some list of ids)`

The conditions will be combined as:
`1 AND 2 AND ( ( 3 OR 4 ) OR 5 OR 6 )`

3 & 4 use the same text for search.

current scaffolding in view:

```py
searchedObjects = BookInstance.objects.filter(public=True)
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    searchedObjects = searchedObjects.exclude(owner=request.user)
filterObj = dict(request.POST)
for key in filterObj:
    if key == 'bookTitleOrDescription':
        #condition 3 & 4
        bookTitleOrDescription = filterObj[key][0]
    elif key == 'author[]':
        #condition 5
        authorList = filterObj[key]
    elif key == 'category[]':
        #condition 6
        categoryList = filterObj[key]
```

`searchedObjects` will have the query result.
The `if, elif`  are required as some parameters may or may not be present. We must avoid writing 10 combinations for it.

models:

```py
class Author(SafeDeleteModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Category(SafeDeleteModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Book(SafeDeleteModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

class BookInstance(SafeDeleteModel):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    public = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Will show in search ?')
    lendable = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='In good condition ?')
```

Comment: Please read the docs for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/ . You already wrote down all your conditions, you simply need to put it into a `filter`. The docs should give you an answer for all your cases ;)

Comment: I read that filter ANDs the conditions. The problem is with the OR conditions. Some parameters among the three may be missing, & query needs be generated without them then. I'm trying to avoid writing like 10 conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in following way:

```
filter = Q()

if key == 'category[]':
    filter = filter |  Q(book__category__id__in='some list of ids')

if key == 'author[]':
    filter = filter |  Q(book__authors__id__in='some list of ids')
....
....

data = BookInstance.objects.filter(filter)
```

Comment: some times the query may be like this:
```(Q(title__icontains='some text') | Q(description__icontains='some text'))  |
            Q(book__authors__id__in='some list of ids') |
            Q(book__category__id__in='some list of ids')```

sometime it may b like this ```Q(book__authors__id__in='some list of ids') |
            Q(book__category__id__in='some list of ids')```

All three parameters of OR may not be present all the time. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your query for each field like this:

```
author = request.POST.get('author', None)
if author:
    searchedObjects = searchedObjects.filter(author=author)
```